# How I Do Sum One Textbox Amount to another Text Box VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have two text boxes `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`. I want to add the `TextBox2` amount in `TextBox1`. I have use the below but the answer is not correct.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox2.Text) + Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = (FormatNumber(TextBox2.Text))
End Sub
```

Comment: *"the answer is not correct"* is NEVER an adequate explanation.  You need to provide ALL the relevant information.  What was the content of each `TextBox`?  What did you expect to happen?  What actually did happen?

Comment: i have already like this amount 200 in textbox1 when i put like 200 in textbox2 then the result showing in textbox1 is 422

Comment: `textBox2.Text = {Integer.Parse(textBox2.Text) + Integer.Parse(textBox1.Text)}.Sum.ToString`

Comment: i got error here

Comment: The Same problem with this code

Comment: Check first if the both text boxes have integers only by `Integer.TryParse(...)`

Comment: Get rid of that second line. It makes no sense anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is where you put your code. It runs every time the text changes.

So, when you enter 2 in the `TextBox2` it adds 2 to the 200 in `TextBox1`. Now `TextBox1` is 202.

You enter 0 in `TextBox2`. `TextBox2` is now 20. The code runs and 20 +202 = 222, the new value in `TextBox1`.

Finally you enter 0. The value in `TextBox1` is 222 + 200 = `422`.

You could see this happen if you set a break point in the code and stepped through line by line.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TB1Integer As Integer
    Dim TB2Integer As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, TB1Integer) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, TB2Integer) Then
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(TB1Integer + TB2Integer)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in both boxes.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I used `Integer.TryParse` to validate the TextBox entries. It is much more reliable than the old Val from VB6. `.TryParse` returns a Boolean so can be used in a an If statement. It also fills the second parameter with the numeric value if successful.

Comment: As ever, a well thought out and well written answer without condescension or criticism.

Comment: @DavidWilson Thank you. I am blushing. It is nice to be appreciated.

Comment: Ha! Not that I'm stalking or anything - I tend to read other people's answers and eventually noticed the above. And thought that it should be applauded.  Sorry for any blushing :-)